# Skype for Business App SDK on iOS - Why does SfBApplication.sharedApplication return nil/null?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

When I retrieve SfBApplication.sharedApplication in viewdidload of my iPhone app's main view controller, I get nil/null but no errors or log info.

What could be causing this?

Specifically I would like to know if the SDK code contains cases when it returns nil here but does not raise an error.

Context: I am using the SDK in the iPhone simulator, and I am accessing the simulator version of the SDK framework from Xamarin - I have created Xamarin iOS bindings for the native framework. I have already seen the SDK working in the iPhone simulator in an Objective-C App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself: this was a problem with the build tools for Xamarin iOS binding projects in Visual Studio.

When I built the same Xamarin iOS Bindings project in Xamarin Studio on the Mac, the SfB App SDK worked - including video calling in the iPhone Simulator.

Lesson learned: create iOS binding projects in Xamarin Studio, on the Mac.